# How to get double rows and merged cells for column titles using rhandsontable?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

[image]

So the above picture is roughly the outcome that I want. 
The key is the double rows and merged cells for the headers so that I can convey the
relatedness of certain columns.

I don't have any code because I don't have a clue on how to even get started.
I know to use the rhandsontable and to implement JavaScript strings for the
renderer parameter.

But I don't know JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I get the table above, with the nested heaers, using r and rhandsontable

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://handsontable.com/docs/7.1.1/demo-nested-headers.html

Comment: Yes, I have seen that page. But still no clue on how to get from here to there.

Comment: Per this thread on GitHub, this feature is not available in the rHandsontable package. https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/204